# Appending a pandas dataframe with new data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append

I'm trying to build a DataFrame of stock data, I can get all the data I need, but can only get 1000 data points at a time. So what I want to do is save the initial 1000 data points in a csv file, and then run my program again every now and again, and any new data, I want to append to the old DataFrame. So it needs to check the 'new df' against the 'old df' and append any new rows.

Lets say my 'old df', saved on a csv file, looks like this:

```
Date     Stock A  Stock B  Stock C  Stock D
01/02/19 100.0    87.0     74.0     228.0
02/02/19 101.5    87.5     75.0     227.0
03/02/19 102.0    89.0     76.5     225.5
```

And I then run my program the next day, and the 'new df' looks like this:

```
Date     Stock A  Stock B  Stock C  Stock D
02/02/19 101.5    87.5     75.0     227.0
03/02/19 102.0    89.0     76.5     225.5
04/02/19 103.0    89.5     77.5     226.0
```

What I then need is for my program to identify that the last row in the 'new df' isn't in the 'old df' and to append the 'old df' with that recent data, in this case:

```
04/02/19 103.0    89.5     77.5     226.0
```

Resulting in the following df, that would then be saved as the 'old df' so I can repeat the process the next day:

```
Date     Stock A  Stock B  Stock C  Stock D
01/02/19 100.0    87.0     74.0     228.0
02/02/19 101.5    87.5     75.0     227.0
03/02/19 102.0    89.0     76.5     225.5
04/02/19 103.0    89.5     77.5     226.0
```

I imagine the code will have to use some variation of:

```
old_df.append(new_df)
```

But with something in there to scan for data that is already in the old_df.

Any help would be much appreciated.

This is my code so far:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

#total_data = pd.read_csv('1m_bin_db.csv')
#total_data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

def get_bars(symbol, interval):
   url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=' + symbol + '&interval=' + interval + '&limit=1000'
   data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   df.columns = ['open_time',
                 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v',
                 'close_time', 'qav', 'num_trades',
                 'taker_base_vol', 'taker_quote_vol', 'ignore']
   df.index = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000.0) for x in df.close_time]
   return df

coins = ['ADABTC']

dfs = []
for coin in coins:
    get_data = get_bars(coin, '1m')
    df = get_data[['o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v']].add_prefix(coin + '_')
    df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
    dfs.append(df)

prices_1m = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
prices_1m.index.name = 'Date'
```

When I print `total_data` from CSV I get:

```
                         ADABTC_o  ADABTC_h    ...     ADABTC_c  ADABTC_v
Date                                           ...                       
2019-02-15 12:41:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011   48805.0
2019-02-15 12:42:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011     837.0
2019-02-15 12:43:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011   19430.0
2019-02-15 12:44:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011   15319.0
2019-02-15 12:45:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011  769414.0
```

When I print `prices_1m` I get:

```
                         ADABTC_o  ADABTC_h    ...     ADABTC_c  ADABTC_v
Date                                           ...                       
2019-02-15 12:43:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011   19430.0
2019-02-15 12:44:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011   15319.0
2019-02-15 12:45:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011  773414.0
2019-02-15 12:46:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011    7449.0
2019-02-15 12:47:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011       0.0
```

So all I want to do is stick the last two rows on the bottom of `total_data` and I did:

```
df = total_data.append(prices_1m).drop_duplicates()
```

Resulting in the following:

```
                            ADABTC_o  ADABTC_h    ...     ADABTC_c  ADABTC_v
Date                                              ...                       
2019-02-15 12:43:59.999     0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011   19430.0
2019-02-15 12:44:59.999     0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011   15319.0
2019-02-15 12:45:59.999     0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011  769414.0
2019-02-15 12:45:59.999000  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011  773414.0
2019-02-15 12:46:59.999000  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011    7449.0
```

So I think the problem is the data is 'live' essentially, so as 12:45:59.999 was the last data point in `total_data` I probably got that data with 10 seconds left to go of the 60 second data period. So in `prices_1m` the 12:45:59.999 data point is updates fully, which explains the difference between the duplicate times but different 'V' column. So I feel like we're almost there, but I want the `prices_1m` to have priority over `total_data`, so the most recent data appended on to `total_data`.

```
2019-02-15 12:45:59.999  0.000011  0.000011    ...     0.000011  773414.0
```

So I want that line to be the entry for `2019-02-15 12:45:59.999`, and then continue appending from there.

I get this when I do print(total_data.index):

```
Index(['2019-02-14 20:06:59.999', '2019-02-14 20:07:59.999',
       '2019-02-14 20:08:59.999', '2019-02-14 20:09:59.999',
       '2019-02-14 20:10:59.999', '2019-02-14 20:11:59.999',
       '2019-02-14 20:12:59.999', '2019-02-14 20:13:59.999',
       '2019-02-14 20:14:59.999', '2019-02-14 20:15:59.999',
       ...
       '2019-02-15 12:36:59.999', '2019-02-15 12:37:59.999',
       '2019-02-15 12:38:59.999', '2019-02-15 12:39:59.999',
       '2019-02-15 12:40:59.999', '2019-02-15 12:41:59.999',
       '2019-02-15 12:42:59.999', '2019-02-15 12:43:59.999',
       '2019-02-15 12:44:59.999', '2019-02-15 12:45:59.999'],
      dtype='object', name='Date', length=1000)
```

Comment: There is DatetimeIndex ?

Comment: Do you need remove all dupes rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need working with `DatetimeIndex` and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), not with `merge` by `date` column:

```
coins = ['ADABTC']

dfs = []
for coin in coins:
    get_data = get_bars(coin, '1m')
    df = get_data[['o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v']].add_prefix(coin + '_')
    df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
    dfs.append(df)

prices_1m = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
prices_1m.to_csv('1m_bin_db.csv')
```

And then:

```
total_data.index = pd.to_datetime(total_data.index)

df = total_data.append(prices_1m)
df = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Comment: if date is index yes. :)

Comment: Ok I'm with ya, that sounds sensible. Let me have a play around with all this and I'll you know. Thanks geezer

Comment: @topbantz - yes, if in each loop shoud be a bit different datetimes in seconds, give me know.

Comment: hi mate, just edited my question. So I still have a small problem basically, I hope I've explained properly.

Comment: @topbantz - Is there DatetimeIndex in `total_data` DataFrame? What return `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: @topbantz - need DatetimeIndex in both DataFrames, check my solution.

Comment: @topbantz - oops, just edited for requirement last dupe index row.

Comment: Mate, that has done the trick, wicked answer, thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Use `append` with `drop_duplicates()` if date is not an index.

```
old_df.append(new_df).drop_duplicates('Date')
```

If data change might be possible and you want latest values to remain:

```
df.append(df1).sort_values('Date',ascending=False).drop_duplicates('Date')
```